# How to open a new window in YII framework 2.0

Tags: yii2

I want to click on a link inside Grid View, which should open a new window in a new tab.
I don't want CHtml::Link answers, since it is YII 1.1, I am using YII 2.0.

THE BELOW CODE IS INSIDE GRID VIEW.

```
['attribute'=>'EMPLOYEEID',
'label'=>'EMPLOYEEID',     
'value'=> Html::a('E_ID', '?r=tb-run-engine/index', ['title' => 'Go']),
                ],
```

I didnt get any value for EMPLOYEEID instead am getting [notset] as value in Grid view.and am not getting hyperlink also.Am new to yii 2.0 can any one help me to figure out this problem??

Comment: This has nothing to do with yii2...

Answer (score 8):

To open link in new tab/window you have to set attribute target="_blank" for this link:

```
<a href="some_url" target="_blank">some text</a>
```

So in Yii2 with Html helper in view file you can write:

```
<?= Html::a("some text","some_url",['target'=>'_blank']) ?>
```

And in yii2 grid you can show raw column:

```
[
  'attribute'=>'name', //your model attribute
  'format'=>'raw',
  'value'=>function ($model, $index, $widget){
     return Html::a(
           $model->name,                     //link text
           ['page/update','id'=>$model->id], //link url to some route
           [                                 // link options
             'title'=>'Go!',
             'target'=>'_blank'
           ]
     );
  }
],
```

Comment: I did whatever u suggested but am getting the following error in "$model->id" ,the first parameter of HTml::a.And the error is "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: if you need to add a class or other html element it should be in the same arrary ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'target'=>'_blank']);

Answer (score 3):

add this to your `Html:a` options `['target' => '_blank', 'data-pjax' => 0]` or turn off pjax in grid

Answer (score 0):

here is my grid view:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
                'dataProvider' => TbRunEngineSearch::$dataprovider_static,
                'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                'id'=>'searchgrid',
                'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

                 [
                'attribute'=>'run_id',
                        'label'=>'field level details', //your model attribute
                'format'=>'raw',
                'value'=>function ($model, $index, $widget){
                    return Html::a(
                            $model->run_id,                     //link text
                            ['page/update','id'=>$model->run_id], //link url to some route
                            [                                 // link options
                                    'title'=>'Go!',
                                    'target'=>'_blank'
                            ]
                    );
                }
                ], 

                ['attribute'=>'run_id',
                'value'=>'product_name',
                'label'=>'Product Name'],

                ['attribute'=>'run_id',
                'value'=>'module_name',
                'label'=>'Module Name'],

                ['attribute'=>'run_id',
                'value'=>'operation_name',
                'label'=>'Operation Name'],

                ['attribute'=>'initiated_at',
                'value'=>'initiated_at',
                'label'=>'Start Time'],

                ['attribute'=>'finished_at',
                'value'=>'finished_at',
                'label'=>'End time'],

                ['attribute'=>'run_id',
                'value'=>'pass_percent',
                'label'=>'Pass %'],

                ['attribute'=>'run_id',
                'value'=>'fail_percent',
                'label'=>'Fail %'],

                ['attribute'=>'run_id',
                'value'=>'operations_num',
                'label'=>'Operations #'],

                ['attribute'=>'build_num_primary',
                'value'=>'build_num_primary',
                'label'=>'Build # Pri/Sec'],

                'run_status',
                'source',

                ['attribute'=>'env_primary',
                'value'=>'env_primary',
                'label'=>'ENV # Pri/Sec '],

                ['attribute'=>'instance_primary',
                'value'=>'instance_primary',
                'label'=>'INSTANCE # Pri/Sec '],    


    ],
                ]);
        ?>
```